# Writing a push and pop in c

Tags: c

Original Q: I'm trying to create this calculator in C for a project. I got the math functions working, but not I am stuck on how to handle the push an pop. Can somebody help me get started? I know what push and pop are supposed to do from java, but I am not sure how to use them without using nodes or an array.

My includes and stack struct:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "stack.h"
#include "debug.h"

#define DEFAULT_CAPACITY 16

struct stack {
   size_t capacity;
   size_t size;
   stack_item *data;
};
```

My attempted push and pop:

**UPDATED**

```
    void push_stack (stack *this, stack_item item) {
   if (full_stack (this)) realloc_stack (this);  
   this->data[this->size++]=item;
}

stack_item pop_stack (stack *this) {
   assert (! empty_stack (this)); 
   if(this->data == NULL){
     fprintf(stderr, "fail");}
   else{
    stack_item tempPop = this->data[this->size--];   
    return tempPop;}
}
```

Updated Q: This is now what I am doing for my push/pop method. I am getting no warnings and no errors, but when I run it, it seg faults after it should pop.

My new question is, does it appear that something I am doing in this block of code is causing my seg fault?

Comment: What about if you use a linked list? it could be very easy

Comment: I do not think this code even compiles. push_stack has argument stack_item but this->data is stack_item*. You push stack_item but pop char*.  One more observation: neither pop nor push changes stack pointer.

Comment: push:`this->data[size++]=item;` pop:`tempPop = this->data[--size];`

Comment: @ The Mask I was going to do something like that, but found out it has to be a stack.

Comment: @VladimirM I was just playing around with it, though it does make sense to make it instead of a char* into an instance of stack_item*.

Comment: *"but found out it has to be a stack."* @BLUEPIXY codes implements a stack. Only if could use a `realloc` wrapper.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I tried this, but it is saying size is undeclared in both instances.

Comment: StackOverflow questions should attempt to show what you have tried and what hasn't worked, rather than present what might be perceived as "here is my homework, it turns out I needed to pay attention in class after all, so now I don't know how to start". It's unclear to me what aspect of this might be confounding you or I'd try and clarify.

Comment: Both of those came blank, those are my attempts. I am no certain how to create these two stack methods as what I had tried is not working and what I would normally do is not the approach allowed. The question is if anybody can help me to understand how to write these methods.

Comment: Oh, it is a `this->size` of course. So think of it as a hint(Pseudo-code) only there.

Comment: Dude, use linked lists.

Comment: `this->data[this->size--]` size decrement earlier case of `pop`. or stack is not initialized correctly configured.　or etc.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm sorry but I don't understand why to dec earlier? Can you elaborate a bit please. I am thinking to pop the top element which is the size - 1, I am not seeing why to dec earlier?

Comment: `size` does not mean the top of the stack data we mean the size of the stack. It is the `size` -1 stack data from a 0 origin.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Okay that is what I meant, since the last element in the array (index size - 1), it is the top of the stack, meaning that is the value I want to pop. Am I not understanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Validation sample code of behavior

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#if 0
 #include "stack.h"
 #include "debug.h"
#else
 typedef char* stack_item;
#endif

#define DEFAULT_CAPACITY 16

struct stack {
   size_t capacity;
   size_t size;
   stack_item *data;
};

typedef struct stack stack;

stack *Stack(void){
    stack *s = malloc(sizeof(stack));
    s->capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
    s->size = 0;
    s->data = malloc(s->capacity * sizeof(stack_item));
    return s;
}

int full_stack(stack *this){
    return this->capacity == this->size;
}

int empty_stack(stack *this){
    return this->size == 0;
}

void realloc_stack(stack *this){
    this->capacity += DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
    this->data = realloc(this->data, this->capacity*sizeof(stack_item));
}

void push_stack (stack *this, stack_item item) {
    if (full_stack (this))
        realloc_stack (this);  
    this->data[this->size++]=item;
}

stack_item pop_stack (stack *this) {
    assert (!empty_stack (this)); 
    if(this->data == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "fail");
        exit(1);//Maybe malloc or realloc
    }
    return this->data[--(this->size)];
}

int main(void){
    stack *s = Stack();
    push_stack(s, "sin");
    push_stack(s, "+");
    push_stack(s, "cos");
    while(!empty_stack(s)){
        puts(pop_stack(s));
    }
    //Stack_(s);//call destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use linked lists.

```
struct stack_element {
    struct stack_element* next; // reserved for stack control
    int data0; // whatever
    int data1;
    int data2;
};

void push_stack(struct stack_element** stack, struct stack_element* element)
{
    element->next = *stack;
    *stack = element;
}

struct stack_element* pop_stack(struct stack_element** stack)
{
    struct stack_element* element = *stack;
    if (element)
        *stack = element->next;
    return element;
}

struct stack_element* stack = NULL; // your stack. its empty
```

Creating new stack element and adding to stack:

```
struct stack_element* element = malloc(sizeof(struct stack_element)); // created new element
element->data0 = 123;
element->data1 = 456;
element->data2 = 789;
push_stack(&stack, element); // stored in stack
```

Fetching an element from stack:

```
struct stack_element* element = pop_stack(&stack);
if (element == NULL)
    printf("Stack was empty, no elements to fetch.");
```

PS: The same element can never be pushed to the stack more than once.

You can also have the stack control separated from the data, in which case you will be able to store the same element more than once:

```
struct stack_control {
    struct stack_control* next;
    void* data;
};

void push_stack(struct stack_control** stack, void* data)
{
    struct stack_control* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct stack_control));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = *stack;
    *stack = temp;
}

void* pop_stack(struct stack_control** stack)
{
    void* data = NULL;
    struct stack_control* temp = *stack;
    if (temp)
    {
        data = temp->data;
        *stack = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return data;
}

struct stack_control* stack = NULL; // empty stack
```

This code the way it is can be used to stack pointers of any type, because `void*` is generic.

Comment: As I said to Andrew, thank you for the code but I was given the struct as source code, and I don't think I am allowed to change it at all, instead I have to just use it to create the push/pop in that way.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you mean when you say "I know what push and pop are supposed to do from java", but please bear in mind that push and pop are just operations that you can do to a data structure that is known as a stack. A stack is more of an idea and that concept can be implemented in any language.

To start of, I would advice you not to use a array. A stack imposes an order in the way you access elements and its perfectly fine with a nice linked list because you only need to remove from the head and add elements to the same head. You typically use an array when you want to access elements at any position in O(1) complexity. The effect of using a linked list is that you dont really have a bound in the number of elements you can add to the stack (unless you really want to).

If you decide to go for a linked list I would advice you to use two structures:

```
struct stack_node {
    int data;
    stack_node* next;
};

struct stack {
    int current_size;
    int max_size;
    struct stack_node head;
};
```

The you can always do

```
void push(struct stack* s, int x){
    if(s->max_size > s->current_size+1){
        add to the stack
    } else {
        stack is full!!
    }
}

int pop(struct stack* s) {
     if(s->current_size == 0){
         Ops! No data in stack, throw error or something
      } else {
         return head and remove item from stack
     }
 }
```

Note that this is only a template to give you an idea... Also, I dont really understand in your code what does "realloc_stack". I think the main problem in your code is that you might still be in a bit of a java minset and programming C requires you to think a bit more low level and do more thinks yourself...

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that "realloc_stack" is unclear, it is another function that I defined in my program that just reallocates memory if the stack is full to make room for new elements.

As for using linked lists, thank you for the code but I was given the struct as source code, and I don't think I am allowed to change it at all, instead I have to just use it to create the push/pop in that way.