# Converting struct linked list to FIFO in C

Tags: c, struct, fifo

I'm using an example provided by Havenard as an answer to this question: [Writing a push and pop in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157199/writing-a-push-and-pop-in-c)

```
struct stack_control {
    struct stack_control* next;
    void* data;
};

void push_stack(struct stack_control** stack, void* data)
{
    struct stack_control* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct stack_control));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = *stack;
    *stack = temp;
}

void* pop_stack(struct stack_control** stack)
{
    void* data = NULL;
    struct stack_control* temp = *stack;
    if (temp)
    {
        data = temp->data;
        *stack = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return data;
}

struct stack_control* stack = NULL; // empty stack
```

It worked well for my purpose, but now things have changed and I would now prefer it to use FIFO rather than LIFO and I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Is the shown code the LIFO you are not interested in or your attempt to do FIFO which does not work?

Comment: First thing you should do, is to keep pointers to both the head *and* the tail of the list. After that, think about where you insert new nodes, and where you remove them. I suggest you try to do it using pen-and-paper first.

Comment: In which way does your FIFO not work? What is wrong?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] to desmonstrate how your FIFO fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing LIFO `pop_stack` routine needs to be rewritten for FIFO:

```
void* pop_stack(struct stack_control** stack)
{
    void* data = NULL;
    struct stack_control *prev = NULL;
    struct stack_control *last = *stack;

    while(last->next != NULL)
      {
      prev = last;
      last = last->next;
      }

    if (last)
    {
        data = last->data;
        free(last);

        if(prev)
          prev->next = NULL;
    }

    return data;
}
```