# Why is the program crashing after assigning a pointer

Tags: c

Managing my linked-list is not working. My program just crashes after I set the value "next" to point on previous "head" of the list and after I search and find an element. What can I do?

The program compiles and starts, but it just crashes returning a random address from the memory.
I've tried to change the function to return the pointer of the new "head" instead of being void, but the result is the same.
By verifying where the program stops i found out that it stops doing "new node->next = (*head)" and on previous attempts with the instruction "return last".
I've tried changing almost completely the function just to understand the problem, but even if i pass a pointer to and already allocated list in the main the address does not work and it crashes.
Just to understand whats going on assume that the the program enters for sure in the if with the condition "type_temp=='A'"

This is the main:

```
#include"devices.h"
#include"stdio.h"
#include"string.h"
#include"stdlib.h"


#define LINE_LENGTH 80
#define COMMAND_LENGTH 30


int main(int argc, char** argvs)
{
    FILE *fp;

    struct Type_A** devices_A = NULL;
    struct Type_B** devices_B = NULL;
    struct Type_C** devices_C = NULL;

    struct Request_Type_C** requests_devices_C = NULL;

    int system_power, usable_power, 
        solar_system_power,solar_system_power_temp;

    int id_temp,power_level_temp;
    int power_level_normal_temp, power_level_low_temp;
    char type_temp;

    char file_line[LINE_LENGTH], command[COMMAND_LENGTH];
    char *sub_line;

    fp = fopen("input1.txt","r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(fgets(file_line,sizeof(file_line),fp) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error reading the first line\n");
        return 1;
    }

    sub_line = strtok(file_line, " ");
    strcpy(command,sub_line);

    sub_line = strtok(NULL, " ");
    system_power = atoi(sub_line);

    usable_power = system_power;

    while(fgets(file_line,sizeof(file_line),fp) != NULL)
    {
        sub_line = strtok(file_line, " ");
        strcpy(command,sub_line);


        if(strcmp(command,"DEVICE_CONNECTED") == 0)
        {
            sub_line = strtok(NULL, " ");
            id_temp = atoi(sub_line);

            sub_line = strtok(NULL, " ");
            type_temp = *sub_line;

            if(type_temp == 'A')
            {
                sub_line = strtok(NULL, " ");
                power_level_normal_temp = atoi(sub_line);

                sub_line = strtok(NULL, " ");
                power_level_low_temp = atoi(sub_line);

                //function with the problem 1
                add_device_a(devices_A,id_temp,type_temp,
                    power_level_normal_temp,power_level_low_temp,0,0);

                //function with the problem 2
                add_device_a_to_system(devices_A,id_temp,&usable_power);
            }
            .
            .
            .
```

**This is the first function with the problem:**

```
void add_device_a(struct Type_A** head, int id, char type,
                    int power_level_normal, int power_level_low,
                    int connected, int consume)
    {
        //allocate the new node
        struct Type_A *new_node = (struct Type_A*) malloc(sizeof(struct Type_A));

        //put in the data
        new_node->id = id;
        new_node->type = type;
        new_node->power_level_normal = power_level_normal;
        new_node->power_level_low = power_level_low;
        new_node->connected = connected;
        new_node->consume = consume;

        //setting the next of the new node
        new_node->next = (*head); <-instruction that generates the problem 
                                    crashing the program 

        //move the head to point to the new node
        (*head) = new_node;

        return;
    } //end add_device_a
```

*This is the second function that generates the problem:*

```
int add_device_a_to_system(struct Type_A** head, int id, int* usable_power)
{
    struct Type_A *node = find_device_a_by_id(head, id);` <-instruction 

                                         that generates the problem
    .
    .
    .
```

**The true function that generates the problem**

```
struct Type_A *find_device_a_by_id(struct Type_A** head, int id)
{
    //used for traverse the list
    struct Type_A *last = *head;

    //check if last is truly the last node
    while(last != NULL)
    {

        //if the id is equal return the pointer to that node
        if(last->id == id) {
                return last; **<-instruction that makes the program crash**
        }
        //else keep going with the next
        last = last->next;
    }

    //didn't find an id equal to the one passed ad parameter
    return NULL;
}//end of *find_device_a_by_id
```

Adding an element to the list should add the element on the linked list as first and modify the pointer to that entry.

Finding an element should return a pointer to that specific entry on the linked-list.

Comment: You don't allocate any memory to `Devices_A`, so you have a problem when you pass that into `add_device_a` and dereference it (as `*head`)

Comment: Are you sure this is a minimal version of your code?  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses;
MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: If you use the normal `[ mcve ]` shorthand (w/o the spaces, of course), it automatically converts it to the new [mcve] text.

Comment: @KenWhite I assume he's well aware and chooses to use the (in my opinion) better and more well-known term regardless.

Comment: I know, @KenWhite — I don't like the totally unnecessary and pointless change, so I don't use it, quite deliberately.  I don't type that spiel out — I have it saved ready for use when needed.

Comment: `if(fp == NULL) { perror("input1.txt"); ...` . Because error messages belong on stderr and should be informative.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: Thanks for your input. I choose not to assume anything. I presume (and it appears that I'm correct) that Jonathan can speak for himself. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: In fact, the full version is: _MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses;
MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
See also
[How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)
and [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)_ but I don't often keep the last two links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a pointer to a pointer to your struct:

```
struct Type_A** devices_A = NULL;
```

Right now it does not point to a valid `struct Type_A*` as you haven't created one to point it to.  So when you pass this into your function `add_device_a` and it dereferences that variable, you invoke undefined behavior, in this case probably a segfault.
What you probably *actually* want is to define `struct Type_A* devices_A = NULL;`  And then when you pass it into your function, pass in the address of that pointer:

```
add_device_a(&devices_A,id_temp,type_temp,
    power_level_normal_temp,power_level_low_temp,0,0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that I had already tryed that and it didn't work, but was surely not the case. Case solved!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to declare `devices_A` as `struct Type_A* devices_A = NULL` (not as a double pointer), and then call `add_device_a()` using `add_device_a(&devices_A, ...`.

The way you're doing it is confusing and requires that you allocate space for `devices_A`, also in this context dereferencing `*head` when `devices_A` is `NULL` is making the program read from address `NULL` which is undefined behavior and may cause crashes.

You can also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157199/writing-a-push-and-pop-in-c) about how to manage linked lists properly.